# Eval with multiple conditions C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have a Eval function and i need multiple conditioned to be evaluated.
In here `news_status` comes like `LOCAL`,`PROVINCIAL`,`MUNICIPAL`,`GLOBAL` if it is a local,provincial or municipal it needs to show LOCAL NEWS otherwise it needs to show the news_status.
I have tried like below.

### My Code

```
  <%# (Eval("news_status") ==("LOCAL" ||"PROVINCIAL || MUNICIPAL") ? "LOCAL NEWS" : Eval("news_status"))%>
```

Comment: And what does it currently show? What's your error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a code-behind method, or I think just make sure to use complete `if` statements on the page. `if(*value*==this || *value*==that...)`

```
Something='<%# GetNews(Eval("news_status")) %>'


public string GetNews(object value)
{
    if (value == "Local" || value == "PROVINCIAL" || value=="MUNICIPAL")
        return "LOCAL NEWS";
    else
        return value;
}
```